# How to Unit Test a Cassandra Datastax Cluster Builder method which returns Session?

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, cassandra, mockito

I have a method in a config class which build's the Cluster for Cassandra connection and returns a Session. [ Spring Boot Application ]
I want to unit test this method using mockito. 
But I'm not able to mock the Cluster.builder().addContactPoint().. this one. I don't know if my approach is wrong. Is it not possible to mock this connection?

I tried with `MockitoJunitRunner.class` and also with `PowerMockRunner.class`
But both case the test is not happening.

This is the snippet inside actual method-

```
cluster = Cluster.builder()

.addContactPoint(applicationConfig.cassandraContactPoint)
            .withCredentials(applicationConfig.cassandraUserName, 
                             applicationConfig.cassandraPassword).withPort(9042).build();

        Session session = cluster.connect();
        return session;
```

This is the test case I'm trying to write-

```
@Test
public void testCassandraConnection_returns_Session() {

    PowerMockito.mockStatic(Cluster.class);
    when(Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(anyString()).withCredentials(anyString(),anyString()).withPort(anyInt()).build()).thenReturn(mockCluster);
}
```

Not Including Assertions here.

I'm getting errors like-

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
> Misplaced or misused argument matcher detected here:...
>
>
> This message may appear after an `NullPointerException` if the last matches is returning an object 
> like `any()` but the stubbed method signature expect a primitive argument, in this case,
> Use primitive alternatives.
>
>     when(mock.get(any())); // bad use, will raise NPE
>     when(mock.get(anyInt())); // correct usage use
>
> Also, this error might show up because you use argument matches with methods that cannot be mocked.
> Following methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode().
> Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.

Comment: Why are you trying to unit test Cassandra's classes to begin with? Are you the author of those classes?

Comment: I am not unit testing cassandra's classes. I have a class which has a method which returns the session object after building a cluster. I want to mock this Cluster.Builder().

Comment: Ah, OK. In that exception message you posted, the dots are supposed to be locations of argument matchers. There are three dots, which I think suggests that mockito doesn't understand your method chaining. I expect the correct way to be something like `when(Cluster.builder()).thenReturn(mockBuilder)` and `when(mockBuilder.build()).thenReturn(mockCluster)`. By the way: are the dots actually dots, or is there some text there?

Comment: Consider posting a complete testclass if `@M.Prokhorov` suggestion doesn't solve your problem. Afaik chaining of mocks (`deep stub mocking`) is not a feature supported by `PowerMockito`.

Comment: Those dots are some text. Dots are not dots. :)
I have resolved the problem by Mocking Cluster.Builder instead of mocking only Cluster class. Now Its working. :) 
Thanks for all the enthusiasm shown.


@Mock
Cluster.Builder mockClusterBuilder will do..and all the when..then calls should be done with this variable. (Like -

when(Cluster.builder()).thenReturn(mockClusterBuilder); when(mockClusterBuilder.addContactPoint(mockApplicationConfig.cassandraContactPoint)).thenReturn(mockClusterBuilder); 

) 

Like this.